# Не работает float left

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не срабатывает `float: left`.

```css
.slider {
 width: 770px;
 height: 305px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 65px;}

    .slider ul {
 width: 770px;
 height: 305px;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;}

    li.slide {
 float: left;
 width: 770px;
 height: 305px;}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <ul>
    <li class="slide"></li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: всё просто : ваш li.slide = 770px и вы даёте ему обтекание слева и разумеется что это всё не помещается

Comment: У Вас ширина каждой `li` равна ширине обертки `ul`. Поэтому `li` располагаются друг под другом.

Comment: Измените ширину либо `li`, либо `ul`

Comment: @smellyshovel, нажмите кнопку Выполнить код. Что вы видите в результате?

Comment: @Visman А что я должен видеть, если `li` пустые? Правилами не рекомендуется изменять исходное содержимое кода. Я лишь поправил форматирование.

Comment: @smellyshovel, а не надо было код преобразовывать раз там все равно ни чего не видно.

Comment: @Visman код CSS и HTML был в одном сегменте. Может я и неправ, что сделал из него сниппет, но как минимум отделить html от css надо было. Да и по сути, код ведь у ТС не работает :) (как и в сниппете)

Comment: Попробуйте так float: left!important;

Comment: @PolonskiyP, что именно не так работает? каков должен быть конечный результат? `float: left` нормально работает, вы можете открыть свой код в инспекторе и посмотреть где начинается `slider` и остальные элементы на странице

Answer (score 1):

Что бы было видно я инлайново добавил фон разный для `li` и что бы было их все видно сделал типа слайдера что ли что бы их было видно , что они существуют

**Почем у вас не было видно их или не срабатывал `float:left` ?**

У вас есть `.slider` и его потомок равен ему и потому не работал `float`

```css
.slider {
  width: 700px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 305px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 65px;
}

.slider ul {
  width: 3500px;
  height: 305px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li.slide {
  float: left;
  width: 700px;
  height: 305px;
  animation: next 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes next {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-700px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(-1400px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-2100px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-2800px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <ul>
    <li class="slide" style="background:red;"></li>
    <li class="slide" style="background:blue;"></li>
    <li class="slide" style="background:green;"></li>
    <li class="slide" style="background:yellow;"></li>
    <li class="slide" style="background:pink;"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так `float: left!important;`